# Cómo agregar un enlace en el menu sidebar para mostrar una Vista en Laravel?

Tags: php, html5, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

Tengo un pequeño proyecto en Laravel, el cual había encontrado en github desde hace algún tiempo(el codigo esta gratis y disponible para todos en este enlace: https://github.com/Karls92/WarehouseSystem). Estoy intentando hacerle algunas modificaciones(para adentrarme en el mundo de Laravel) como por ejemplo mostrar la vista de administración de usuario (donde se Listan, agregan, editan y eliminan usuarios). La ruta, vista, el modelo y el controlador lo tiene hecho, pero no he logrado que se agregue el enlace usuarios en la barra de menu, para el usuario con privilegio administrador(type: admin, level: 0); por lo que se me ha hecho imposible agregar y eliminar usuarios del sistema.

Aquí dejo el código del sidebar menu, donde se muestran los módulos activos para cada usuario dependiendo del nivel. El usuario administrador debe tener el modulo de usuarios activo pero eso no sucede, no sale en el sidebar menú.

Archivo basic_list.blade.php

```
      @extends('backend.general.main')

      @section('content')
      @include('backend.general.charging_modal')
      @include('backend.general.image_preview_modal')
      @include('backend.general.confirmation_delete_modal')

<div class="box box-default color-palette-box">
    <div class="nav-tabs-custom">
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
            <?php
                if(!isset($active_submodule) || !isset($lateral_elements[$active_module][$active_submodule]))
                {
                    ?>
                    <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="<?=$lateral_elements[$active_module]['url'];?>"><?=trans('messages.plural.'.$active_module);?></a></li>
                    <?php
                }
                else
                {
                    if(isset($lateral_elements[$active_module][$active_submodule]))
                    {
                        foreach($lateral_elements[$active_module] as $submodule => $details)
                        {
                            if($submodule == 'details')
                            {
                                continue;
                            }

                            ?>
                            <li role="presentation" <?= $active_submodule == $submodule ? 'class="active"' : '' ;?>><a href="<?=$details['url'];?>"><?=trans('messages.plural.'.$submodule);?></a></li>
                            <?php
                        }
                    }
                }
            ?>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="box-body">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                @include('flash::message')
            </div>

            @yield('list_content')
        </div><!--row-->
    </div><!--box-body-->
</div><!--box-->
       @endsection

     @section('css_template_header')
       <?=plugins_css_dir('datatables/dataTables.bootstrap.css')."\n";?>
       <style>

        </style>
       @endsection

      @section('js_template_footer')
      <?=plugins_js_dir('datatables/jquery.dataTables.min.js')."\n";?>
      <?=plugins_js_dir('datatables/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js')."\n";?>
      <?=js_dir('custom_datatable.js')."\n";?>
      <?=js_dir('list_script.js')."\n";?>

      <script>
       $(document).ready(function()
          {

          });
       </script>
       @endsection
```

Fragmento de codigo donde se encuentran las rutas para acceder a la vista de la pantalla usuarios

routes.php

```
           #grupos de rutas de usuarios
Route::group(['prefix' => 'usuarios'], function ()
{
    Route::get('/', [
        'as'   => 'users.index',
        'uses' => 'Backend\UsersController@index'
    ]);

    Route::get('agregar', [
        'as'   => 'users.store',
        'uses' => 'Backend\UsersController@add'
    ]);
    Route::post('agregar', [
        'as'   => 'users.store',
        'uses' => 'Backend\UsersController@store'
    ]);

    Route::get('editar/{username}', [
        'as'   => 'users.update',
        'uses' => 'Backend\UsersController@edit'
    ])->where(['username' => '^(?!agregar)[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$']);
    Route::post('editar/{username}', [
        'as'   => 'users.update',
        'uses' => 'Backend\UsersController@update'
    ])->where(['username' => '^(?!agregar)[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$']);

    Route::get('eliminar/{id}', [
        'as'   => 'users.delete',
        'uses' => 'Backend\UsersController@delete'
    ])->where(['id' => '[0-9]+']);
});
```

Entro al sistema como administrador y si intento acceder a la vista de usuarios colocando la ruta localhost/admin/usuarios directamente en el navegador me arroja el siguiente error:

```
             ErrorException in 948f09d8bf6aa49f052b757bf97cfa04 line 13:
             Undefined index: users (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\proyecto-almacen\backend\resources\views\backend\general\basic_list.blade.php) (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\proyecto-almacen\backend\resources\views\backend\general\basic_list.blade.php)
```

Qué me estara faltando hacer para poder mostrar  la opción en el menu sidebar para los usuarios administradores?
PD: El sistema lo tengo actualmente instalado en Local, base de datos: Mysql.

Comment: Solo te informa que la ruta no existe, especificamente el de `users.index`, pero al parecer ese solo es el comienso, tedriamos que ver tus variabes, esa la de `lateral_elemets`, o talvez simplemente es partes como `"<?=$details['url'];?>"` que deberian de ser `"<?=route($details['url'];)?>"`, creo yo. te lo digo sin saber que contiene `$details`

Comment: He encontrado donde esta la variable lateral_elements, la ruta de users.index si existe y esta bien, el problema ya lo encontre. En la parte donde se llenaba el arreglo lateral_elements, el script php que agregaba la ruta user al menu lateral estaba comentada, por eso no salia. Ya lo solucioné... Gracias!